# Incorrect Routing Times in ArcGIS Desktop 10.7

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, routing, distance-matrix

I'm trying to find an OD Cost Matrix for a sample of zip codes in LA, San Bernardino, and Clark (NV) Counties using TIGER Data found here: https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2012/ROADS/ (the files I used are 06037, 06071, and 32003)-- but the times are 50%+ off from Google maps.
Specifically, I used the Integrate tool on all three, with a clustering tolerance of .001 decimal degrees, since the original shapefiles have gaps and so can't perform routing analysis. (Integrating by 100m made little difference).

I then used Project to change the shapefiles' coordinate systems to "USA_Contiguous_Equidistant_Conic" and outputted to feature classes in a feature dataset.
Now that the integrated and projected shapefiles are in a feature dataset, and because they're in projected coordinates, all the lengths of the roads are listed in meters. I created a new field that divides that length by 1609.34 to get the length in miles. I also assigned each road a speed in miles/second based on its road type in a new field. (e.g. a highway, as defined by the Census, has a speed of 70/3600 miles/sec). The VB code I used was:

```
speed = 25/3600
Select Case [RTTYP]
Case "C"
speed = 40/3600
Case "I"
speed = 70/3600
Case "M"
speed = 30/3600
Case "O"
speed = 30/3600
Case "S"
speed = 50/3600
Case "U"
speed = 55/3600
End Select
```

All this created the following attribute table for each feature class:

[image]

I then created a network dataset, with global turns and an attribute for "time" in seconds, which is just the length of each road in miles divided by its speed in miles/second:

[image]

I then used a few zipcodes from my own data to create a 15 x 15 ODCM using the Network Analyst tool box.

As I've mentioned, this is way off from Google Maps, and upon closer inspection it seems like everything is connected, but the program simply ignores the most optimal routes. For instance, ArcMap says to drive from Las Vegas to Los Angeles requires driving on unnamed dirt roads in the desert. The difference in the routes are apparent especially in the beginning of the route near Vegas:

[image]

[image]

I also tried creating a hierarchy where roads the Census calls primary roads are primary, secondary are secondary, and all the rest are tertiary. However, when I did this, ArcMap couldn't find any routes! I am also sure that the primary roads are connected; I created a topology using the three shapefiles with the rule "Must Not Have Dangles". It seems like most of those errors occur when roads actually end, and so there seem to be no discontinuities:

[image]

Earlier, when I projected and then integrated (still by .001 decimal degrees), the errors were about the same. Interestingly, when I try to integrate before projecting, ArcGIS often throws a topological error, noting that there's an "undetected intersection." Integrating by .01 decimal degrees only made the errors worse.

I also tried this method on the shapefile for Cook County, IL, and its errors compared to Google Maps were only about 3%. Finally, I did the same using the "primary and secondary" roads in Indiana and Illinois, and the average error was only 5%.

I have no idea what happened. Are there other data sources which don't require messing around with the Integrate tool (I tried using the OSRM API, but it seemed inaccurate compared to Google Maps)?